# Which encoding uses the \x (backslash x) prefix?

Tags: encoding, internationalization

I'm attempting to decode text which is prefixing certain 'special characters' with **\x**. I've worked out the following mappings by hand:

```
\x28   (
\x29   )
\x3a   :

e.g. 12\x3a39\x3a03 AM
```

Does anyone recognise what this encoding is?

Comment: Note that it is likely that \x3a39 is a single unit - it would be in C, at any rate.  If the string was a wide-character string, it might fit in a single character; in an 8-bit character string, it would overflow, and the value inserted is probably undefined (implementation defined at best).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). All occurrences of the four characters `\xST` are converted to 1 character, whose ASCII code is `ST` (in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)), where `S` and `T` are any of `0123456789abcdefABCDEF`.

Comment: You can easily decode this type of text by just putting it into quotes in an interactive Python interpreter.

Comment: @PaulFisher can you provide a hint exactly how?

Comment: @Imray in a console, run 'python' (or 'ipython'), and then at the prompt, type in [ '12\x3a39\x3a03 AM' ] (i.e., everything between the brackets, including the quotes, but excluding the brackets).

Comment: Strange, I tried with '\x9fX#`\x9f' and it's kept like this, @PaulFisher

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica That's because in your case, `\x9f` is not a printable Unicode character -- it is the control character "Application Program Command". Python will escape unprintable characters when printing the `repr` of a string. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+009F

Comment: Note that in C and C++, a `\x` sequence is not limited to two hex digits; it will use as many hex digits as follow the `\x` producing an implementation-defined value.  See C11 [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) for more information — contrast the rules for octal and hexadecimal values.  Other languages may have different rules.

Answer (score 27):

The `'\xAB'` notation is used in C, C++, Perl, and other languages taking a cue from C, as a way of expressing hexadecimal character codes in the middle of a string.

The notation `'\007'` means use octal for the character code, when there are digits after the backslash.

In C99 and later, you can also use `\uabcd` and `\U00abcdef` to encode Unicode characters in hexadecimal (with 4 and 8 hex digits required; the first two hex digits in `\U` must be `0` to be valid, and often the third digit will be `0` too — `1` is the only other valid value).

Note that in C, octal escapes are limited to a maximum of 3 digits but hexadecimal escapes are not limited to 2 or 3 digits; the hexadecimal escape ends at the first character that's not a hexadecimal digit.  In the question, the sequence is `"12\x3a39\x3a03"`.  That is a string containing 4 characters: `1`, `2`, `\x3a39` and `\x3a03`.  The actual value used for the 4-digit hex characters is implementation-defined.  To achieve the desired result (using `\x3A` to represent a colon `:`), the code would have to use string concatenation:

```
"12\x3a" "39\x3a" "03"
```

This now contains 8 characters: `1`, `2`, `:`, `3`, `9`, `:`, `0`, `3`.

Answer (score 9):

I use [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) for this sort of thing.

If you [drop it in the input field and drag Magic](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Magic(3,false,false,%27%27)&input=XHgyOFx4MjlceDNh) from the Favourites list into the recipe it'll tell you the conversion and that you could've used [the From_Hex recipe with a \x delimiter](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27%5C%5Cx%27)&input=XHgyOFx4MjlceDNh).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you are dealing with is a unicode string that has been encoded differently than the output stream it was sent to.  ie. a utf-16 string output to a latin-1 device.  In that situation, certain characters will be outputted as escape values to avoid sending control characters or wrong characters to the output device.  This happens in python at least.

Comment: So my question @lostlogic, how does one get the original encoding that was supposed to have been sent. I do have a similar problem