# How to convert \xXY encoded characters to UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a text which contains characters such as "\xaf", "\xbe", which, as I understand it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889941/which-encoding-uses-the-x-backslash-x-prefix), are ASCII encoded characters.

I want to convert them in Python to their UTF-8 equivalents. The usual `string.encode("utf-8")` throws `UnicodeDecodeError`. Is there some better way, e.g., with the `codecs` standard library?

Sample [200 characters here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/893551/encoding-sample).

Comment: Your sample doesn't include any `\xaf` or the like.  Do you have any samples with such characters?

Comment: Your sample data *is* valid UTF-8.  With the "record separator" and "unit separator" control characters.

Comment: According to `enca` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) it is UTF-8 "surrounded by/intermixed with non-text data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is already a UTF-8 encoded file.

```
# saved encoding-sample to /tmp/encoding-sample
import codecs
fp= codecs.open("/tmp/encoding-sample", "r", "utf8")
data= fp.read()

import unicodedata as ud

chars= sorted(set(data))
for char in chars:
    try:
        charname= ud.name(char)
    except ValueError:
        charname= "<unknown>"
    sys.stdout.write("char U%04x %s\n" % (ord(char), charname))
```

And manually filling in the unknown names:
char U000a LINE FEED
char U001e INFORMATION SEPARATOR TWO
char U001f INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE

Comment: Thanks, you're right the short sample I've provided is UTF-8. however (unfortunately) in the whole file, there are parts encoded in various other encodings (mostly windows-1250). I have solved this by `try`ing to  `"string".decode()` for the most common encodings and, if everything failed, guessing the encoding with the `chardet` library.

Answer (score 3):

`.encode` is for converting a Unicode string (`unicode` in 2.x, `str` in 3.x) to a a byte string (`str` in 2.x, `bytes` in 3.x).

In 2.x, it's legal to call `.encode` on a `str` object.  Python implicitly decodes the string to Unicode first: `s.encode(e)` works as if you had written `s.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).encode(e)`.

The problem is that the default encoding is "ascii", and your string contains non-ASCII characters.  You can solve this by explicitly specifying the correct encoding.

```
>>> '\xAF \xBE'.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
'\xc2\xaf \xc2\xbe'
```

Comment: That's fine but the rest of the text is encoded as UTF-8 (at least this was reported by `enca`). So this procedure cannot be applied for the whole text.

Comment: So the \xXY characters are in ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 2):

It's not ASCII (ASCII codes only go up to 127; `\xaf` is 175). You first need to find out the correct encoding, decode that, and then re-encode in UTF-8.

Could you provide an actual string sample? Then we can probably guess the current encoding.

Comment: That sample doesn't look like an encoded text to me, more like a proprietary format.

Comment: It should be in the MARC format (http://www.loc.gov/marc/). When I tried to detect its encoding with `enca` I got response saying that it's mostly UTF-8 interspersed with non-text characters.

Comment: So it definitely is not a text format/encoding. This is not a problem you can solve with a correct encoding; you need a library that can read this "database".  Something [like this](http://www.oss4lib.org/taxonomy/term/67) perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using the `pymarc` library to parse the file. The problem is that it can't parse it correctly because of these characters (\xaf...). So I'm trying to repair the file before passing it to the parser.