# How to detect undecoded characters in python?

Tags: python, string, csv, encoding, python-2.x

Im getting data from a csv file, doing something with it and then writing it to a text template.

The problem occurs when I come across characters that I cannot encode.

For example, when I come accross a value written in chinese, the selected field is blank when I open it with some kind of a csv editor (e.g. LibreOffice Calc for Linux).

But when I get the data via csv.reader in my script, I can see that it is actually a string that hasn't been decoded properly.
And when I try to write it to a template, I get this weird **SUB** string.

Here is the breakdown of the problem:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
    # take value from the row and store it in a dictionary
    ....
    # take the values from the dictionary and write them to a template
    with open('template.txt', 'r+') as template:
        src = Template(template.read())
        content = src.substitute(rec)

    with open('myoutput.txt', 'w') as bill:
        bill.write(content)
```

And the template.txt looks like this:

```
$name
$address
$city
...
```

All of this generates txt files like this:

```
Bill
North Grove 14
Scottsdale
...
```

If any of the dictionary values are empty, e.g. an empty string `''`, my template rendering function ignores the tag, so for example if the `address` attribute was missing from a particular row, the output would be

```
Bill
Scottsdale
...
```

When I try to do that with my chinese data, my function does write the data because the strings in question are not empty. And when I write them to a template, the end result looks like this:

```
    SUB
    SUB
    Hong Kong
    ...
```

How can I display my data properly? Also is there a way to skip that data, for example something that can try to decode the data, and if it's not successful, convert it to an empty string.
P.S. `try except` won't work here, because `mystring.encode('utf-8')` or `mystring.encode('latin-1')` will encode the string, but it will still be outputted as garbage.

**EDIT**

After printing out the problem row, the output of the problematic values is the following:

```
{'Name': '\x1a \x1a\x1a', 'State': '\x1a\x1a\x1a'}
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? What is the encoding of your csv file? How do you know that your file contains valid data (if both LibreOffice and Python are not working, I guess you are using a third tool)?

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini I don't know the encoding of the csv file, it's not mine. I also don't know if the file contains valid data.

Comment: Try asking file: `file name-of-csv-file`. It should return something like `a.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text`.

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini it returned filename.csv: data

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini it's in the question update

Comment: This may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889941/which-encoding-uses-the-x-backslash-x-prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x1a` is the [ASCII substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character). This is the reason why you see "SUB" in your output. This character is generally used as a replacement by programs that try to decode bytes but fail.

Your CSV file does not contain valid data. Probably it was generated starting from a source containing valid data, but the file itself does not contain valid data anymore.

<sup>Just guessing: perhaps, did you open the file with LibreOffice and then saved it?</sup>

---

If you want to check whether your string contains ASCII unprintable characters, use this:

```
def is_printable(data):
    return all(c in string.printable for c in data)
```

If you want to remove ASCII unprintable characters:

```
def strip_unprintable(data):
    return ''.join(c for c in data if c in string.printable)
```

If you want to deal with Unicode strings, then replace `c in string.printable` with:

```
ord(c) > 0x1f and ord(c) != 0x7f and not (0x80 <= ord(c) <= 0x9f)
```

(Credit goes to [What is the range of Unicode Printable Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andrea Corbellini, your answer helped me find a solution.

```
def stringcheck(line):
    for letter in line:
        if letter not in string.printable:
            return 0
    return 1
```

However I don't think this is the most pythonic way of doing this, so any suggestions on how to make this better would be much appreciated.