# Decoding hex (ASCII) in python

Tags: python, shell, encoding, ascii

I am trying to make a programm, that interacts with **Windows** shell, so I tried these commands:

```
output = subprocess.run('ipconfig', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output.stdout

output = os.popen('ipconfig','r',1).read()
```

but some of the output (on Russian language) is represented in hex (ASCII):

```
Wireless LAN adapter \x81\xa5\xe1\xaf\xe0\xae\xa2\xae\xa4\xad\xa0\xef \xe1\xa5\xe2\xec 4:
```

should be

```
Wireless LAN adapter Беспроводная сеть 4:
```

I need all output info to be text.

By the way, when I use **os.popen('ipconfig', 'w')** in write mode, the output is correct and there is no hex values, just text, but I can't save it to integer.

Some already asked questions, that I found...

[Which encoding uses the \x (backslash x) prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/889950)

[Decode Hex String in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284069/12569676)

Thank's 4 help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
output.decode('cp866')
```

The output from subprocess should be a `bytes` object (in Python 3), using your example:

```py
b'Wireless LAN adapter \x81\xa5\xe1\xaf\xe0\xae\xa2\xae\xa4\xad\xa0\xef \xe1\xa5\xe2\xec 4:'.decode('cp866')
> 'Wireless LAN adapter Беспроводная сеть 4:'
```

In general, you need to know which encoding your system is using, `cp866` is used for Russian, check
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

You can also query your system default encoding with

```py
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

And if it matches, you don't even need to specify it when calling `bytes.decode`.